# R named lists with keywords and postForm in RCurl

Tags: r, list, rcurl

I'm trying to use postForm to log in to a website.  The form requires a field called "next".  postForm takes the form fields as a list called .params.  But R cannot have a list where one of the names is "next":

```
> list(next="hi")
Error: unexpected '=' in "list(next="
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try quotes:

```
list('next'="hi")
```